# Bootstrap btn-block not working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, django-generic-views

I'm trying to expand the submit button so that it is the size of the password field. I am using the code btn-block but it's not working.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row" style="margin-top:60px;">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">


      <div class="span12" style="text-align:center; margin: 0 auto;">
        <form class="form-horizontal" style="width: 400px; margin: 0 auto;" method="post">
          <fieldset>
            <h3 style="color:dimgray;" class="sign-up-title">
              Bem-vindo de volta! Efetue seu login
            </h3>
            <hr class="colorgraph">
            <legend>
              Efetue seu login
            </legend>
            <div style='display:none'>
              <input type='hidden' name='csrfmiddlewaretoken' value='ImQqDNXbmiVQKGo3OsZlrepAzwfAu70B' />
            </div>
            <tr>
              <th>
                <label for="id_username">
                  Usuário:
                </label>
              </th>
              <td>
                <input id="id_username" type="text" name="username" maxlength="30" />
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th>
                <label for="id_password">
                  Senha:
                </label>
              </th>
              <td>
                <input type="password" name="password" id="id_password" />
              </td>
            </tr>

            <div  class="buttonHolder">
              <input type="submit" value="Entrar" class="btn btn-large btn-success btn-block" id="submit-login"/>
            </div>
          </fieldset>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: http://i60.tinypic.com/2n7fpz5.png]

Comment: btn-block makes the button a block-level element.  This makes it span the width of it's parent.  What does it look like now?

Comment: Where is the problem? It works fine.

Comment: May I ask why are you using `<tr>` & `<th>` tags?

Comment: I'm using django generic view. He creates these tr th.

Answer (score 66):

In Bootstrap 5.0.x, `btn-block` is depreciated, and to get a full width button you can use a grid system and use `col-12` in the button class.

you can check out the documentation from [bootstrap documentation page](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/buttons/#block-buttons)

Comment: It likely has been removed if it is not working. Deprecated means it is still there and will be removed in the future.

Answer (score 57):

People from google, just add `w-100` to your button to make it full width (the way `btn-block` used to work):

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary w-100">Login</button>
```

Comment: This doesn't work properly as it doesn't take into account the padding of the button - making the inner width 100%, while the padding will be added on top of it, making the button get out of bounds.

Answer (score 8):

Works once you add w-100 to the button class.

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary w-100">Login</button>
```

Answer (score 5):

Why not follow the official documentation of Bootstrap 5

**Just add d-grid class in outer div**

```
d-grid
```

Full syntax

```
 <div class="row mb-3">
     <div class="d-grid">
       <button class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
     </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 5):

The `btn-block` class is a combination of `display: block` and `width: 100%`, so we must use the `d-block w-100` classes. Of course, if it is necessary to use ‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍`display: block‍`, otherwise `w-100` is enough

```html
<div class="buttonHolder">
    <input type="submit" value="Entrar" class="btn btn-large btn-success w-100 d-block" id="submit-login"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Use "col-12" or use "w-100". Both will work at making a button full width relative to it's container.

Answer (score 2):

try to use w-100 inside class
like that `<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary w-100">Login</button>`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

You can use this method in Bootstrap version 5

```
<div class="w-100">
    <button class="btn btn-primary w-100" type="button">Button</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem but my `btn-block` wasn't working within a modal. 
This was because the button was in bootstrap 4's footer. Once I moved it to the modal's body, it worked just fine. I hope this might help someone.

Answer (score 1):

I'm just facing a similar situation here, d-block doesn't work in bootstrap5, so using w-100, will give the button a width of 100% the parental allowance.

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary w-100 btn-lg">Sign Up</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

set the display value to inline-block and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same Issue where btn-block was not working in bootstrap 4, in a modal-body. 
the Issue was that it was inside in a column `<div class="col-xs-12">` and that parent element was not filling the expected 100%. The fix was to replace the `col-xs-12` with `col` so the parent looks like this after the fix  `<div class="col-xs-12">`. 
The root cause is that the styling is using flexbox.
To have better understanding see the documentation  for bootstrap 4 here... [Bootstrap 4 Grid Documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/)

For the solution of the above, you should add the `col` class to the `buttonHolder` or replace `buttonHolder` with col `completely`

Answer (score 0):

**btn-block** refer to their parent( div with class="buttonHolder"), which their size fit with "Entrar" word.

`<div  class="buttonHolder">
    <input type="submit" value="Entrar" class="btn btn-large btn-success btn-block" id="submit-login"/>
</div>`

So, delete their div (div with class="buttonHolder") and Button with btn-block can have same size with the password field.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `.col-bg-12` class and it will work the same as block.
I had this same problem but using this solved it so hopefully it will be helpful to you too.

Answer (score 0):

The simple method will be just give col-12 to the btn class

Answer (score 0):

U can use class=btn h-100, class=btn col-12 or in div tag d-grid``

Answer (score 0):

just add `col-12` to the class.

`btn-block` doesn't work with bootstrap5

---

Answer (score 0):

in Bootstrap 5 btn-block is deprecated, visit
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/components/buttons/#block-buttons
for options for using btn-block. Use display and gap utilities for block display of buttons, below is an example from the above link

```html
<div class="d-grid gap-2">
  <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">Button</button>
  <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">Button</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Or maybe try the following:

```html
<a href="#" class="btn btn-success btn-toolbar d-flex justify-content-center">Confirm</a>
```